# How is the name Shiva connected with the ruling aspect of the Supreme Lord?

Tags: scripture, vedas, shiva, puranas, brahman

**Lord Shiva** is called by [many names](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/13649/what-names-of-lord-shiva-used-today-are-from-vedas/13650#13650) and the name 'Shiva' is one of the most popular names! The names Maheswara, Parameswara, Ishana, Isha, Pashupati, etc denote that Lord is Ruler due to these names having "Isha" and "Pati" in them which denotes the ruling aspect. Even in Vedas and Ithihasas Lord is frequently called by these names. For example in Valmiki Ramayana:

> इदं शुभतरं वाक्यं व्याजहार **महेश्वरः** | ६-११९-१  Maheswara thereupon delivered the following still more beautiful speech: 
> अर्चिष्मद्भिर्वृतो भाति भूतैरिव महेश्वरः || ६-७१-१३  He is shining like **Maheswara** surrounded by ghosts, with resplendent and sharp spikes. 
> हिमवत्प्रभवे शृंगे सह देव्या **महेश्वरः** || १-३६-२६ Maheswara settled down along with his consort Uma on the peak of a mountain emerged from Himalayas.

Similarly, in Vedic texts like:

> अथ कस्मादुच्यते **भगवान्महेश्वरः**। *(Atharvasira)* Why is he called Bhagavan Maheswara? 
> मायिनं च **महेश्वरम्** । *(Svetasvatara)* Maheswara is the controller of Maya

The name Maheswara contains "Ishwara" inherently inside it and hence it denotes the Lordship aspect of Lord ie as Ruler of all.

Similarly, another popular name [Ishana](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16553/who-are-pancha-brahmas-lalita-devi-sits-on-and-why-are-they-called-so/16557#16557) also means the Supreme Ruler. Another name [Isha](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16594/why-is-lord-shiva-called-pashupati-who-are-the-pashus/16596?r=SearchResults&s=14%7C11.7659#16596) also denotes the same. If we look at the name [Pashupati](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16594/why-is-lord-shiva-called-pashupati-who-are-the-pashus/16596?r=SearchResults&s=14%7C11.7659#16596) also it inherently contains Pati which means Lord of all. The name [Rudra](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/36598/what-are-the-etymologies-for-the-word-rudra/46460#46460) also denotes inherent prowess and is thus related to the ruling aspect. Name [Sharva](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21725/what-are-the-eight-forms-ashtamurti-of-lord-shiva/21728?r=SearchResults&s=8%7C5.8049#21728) is also connected with destroying aspect and thus connected with the Ruling aspect.

But if we Look at the name Shiva, it is mostly associated with aspects like:

> [Auspiciousness](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/902/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-word-shiva/903?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C79.7451#903)
> [Turiya State](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/902/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-word-shiva/16933?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C81.4875#16933)
> [Purifying](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/18594/how-can-a-chandala-purify-himself/18596?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C215.3084#18596)

The name Shiva has special importance as the Purana is also named "Shiva Purana" after Shiva's name. Vedas also speak of the glory of Shiva Nama and the [Panchakshari mantra](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/46102/which-scripture-says-that-vedas-sri-rudram-panchakshari-mantra-and-the-word/47834?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C108.7740#47834) also contains the name, Shiva.

Does the name **Shiva** also has an aspect that is connected with the ruling aspect of the Lord ie, which gives the meaning of Ishwara or Ruler?

Comment: vishnu is really reffered as shiva (nirmala) spatika one which doesnt have blimsh is called shiva.. Shiva is the primary diety of Sky. Shiva means sky tattva.. primarily

Comment: sivas shivathomdar rasa (vishnushasranama)

Comment: @PrasannaR Lord Kartikeya is really referred as shiva.. spatika one which doesnt have blimsh is called shiva.. Shiva is the primary diety of Sky. Shiva means sky tattva.. primarily ----- shwetachhavi shaktimaya shiva (kartikeyasahasranama)

Comment: @PrasannaR Lord Surya is really referred as shiva.. spatika one which doesnt have blimsh is called shiva.. Shiva is the primary diety of Sky. Shiva means sky tattva.. primarily -----shiva skandah prajapati (aditya hridaya),  bhavitatman bhutantakaranah shiva (suryasahasranama)

Comment: @PrasannaR Shree Bhavani is really referred as shiva.. spatika one which doesnt have blimsh is called shiva.. Shiva is the primary diety of Sky. Shiva means sky tattva.. primarily ----- shivoma paramashaktir ananta (parvatisahasranama)

Comment: @PrasannaR Shree Mahalakshmi is really referred as shiva.. spatika one which doesnt have blimsh is called shiva.. Shiva is the primary diety of Sky. Shiva means sky tattva.. primarily ----- shivadhatri subhananda (srilaskhamisahasranama)

Comment: @PrasannaR Shree MahaGanapati is really referred as shiva.. spatika one which doesnt have blimsh is called shiva.. Shiva is the primary diety of Sky. Shiva means sky tattva.. primarily ----- shivorudroishashakti (ganapatisahasranama) –

Comment: what is your point so you dont have question right.. you are already decide.. you are using this forum to preach right.. then you dont require answer

Answer (score 7):

**Yes**, the name Shiva itself also denotes that Lord is the Ruler also. **If we reverse the word Shiva (शिव) we get the word Vashi (वशी)** which means 'who is the controller of all' which has a similar meaning as Isha/Ishwara. Shiva Purana Vidyesvara Samhita explains it as:

> शिवस्तथा प्रकृत्यादि वशीकृत्याधितिष्ठति |
> **सर्वं वशीकृतं यस्मात्तस्माच्छिव इति स्मृतः** |
> शिव एव हि सर्वज्ञः परिपूर्णश्च निःस्पृहः || ११ || *(Chapter 18)* 
>  
> Shiva keeps Prakrit etc. just as he pleases. **He is called Shiva because he has brought everything under his control (Vashikrita)**. Shiva alone is omniscient, perfect, and free from desire.

Thus, Shiva is the one who has everything under his control (Vashi).

> प्रपंचसारसर्वस्वमनेनैव वशीकृतम् || ७४ ||
> तस्मादस्य **वशीकर्ता** नास्तीति स **शिवः** स्मृतः |
> यथा सर्वमृगाणां च हिंसको मृगहिंसकः || ७५ ||
> अस्य हिंसामृगो नास्ति तस्मात्सिंह इतीरितः *(Chapter 18)* 
>  
> **The word Shiva signifies him who controls everything and whom none can control, (Shiva Vashi)** just as Simha signifies the creature who attacks other animals and whom other animals cannot attack (Simha Himsa).

Just as the animal which does Himsa on deers is called Simha (Himsa-Simha), similarly he who controls everything (Vashi) is called Shiva.

Even the Upanishads use the word Vashi to denote the Supreme controller:

> **एको वशी सर्वभूतान्तरात्मा** एकं रूपं बहुधा यः करोति ।
> तमात्मस्थं ये'नुपश्यन्ति धीरास्तेषां सुखं शाश्वतं नेतरेषाम् ॥ Katha Upanishad 2.2.12 
> **One Vashi (controller), the internal atman of all living things** who makes his own form diverse to the intelligent who realizes him as seated in the self, eternal bliss is theirs, not others.

Svetasvatara Upanishad uses both words "Shiva" and "Vashi" while describing Supreme Lord:

> एको **वशी** निष्क्रियाणां बहूनामेकं बीजं बहुधा यः करोति । 12 ॥ 
> here is a One **Vashi** (Ruler) of the actionless many; He makes the one seed manifold.
>
> **वशी** सर्वस्य लोकस्य स्थावरस्य चरस्य च ॥ १८॥ 
> He is **Vashi** (controller) of all Lokas, moving and nonmoving.
>
> सर्वव्यापी स भगवांस्तस्मात् सर्वगतः **शिवः** ॥ ११॥ 
> He is all-pervasive Bhagavan that is why he is called **Shiva**.
>
> घृतात् परं मण्डमिवातिसूक्ष्मं ज्ञात्वा **शिवं** सर्वभूतेषु गूढम् । 
> He who knows Brahman, who is **Shiva**, extremely subtle, like the film that rises to the surface of clarified butter and is hidden in all beings

Thus, even the reverse of the name of the Lord can contain great mysteries just like Lord Shiva is Vashi.

Comment: Why u answered 2 times

Comment: @PrasannaR where did I answer twice?..

Comment: Question itself looks like answer